# Run batch file when starting excel

Tags: excel, batch-file, cmd, automation

I do have a question: is there a way, when user double clicks on excel file, batch or cmd file will be launched, which will launch that clicked excel file? We would like to save further a log of employees how frequent they are using files in their computers.
I need to use batch or cmd files as excel files are in other computers and we will be using group policy for an incorporation that script

Comment: you could play around with `assoc` and `ftype`. Should be possible. Of course only, if the files are opened with doubleclick. When they are opened via Excel "open file", this fails.

Comment: hello Stephan, yeas that's the key that it should launch with double clik on excel file. Will try your suggestion i write if succeed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using VBA. In the "ThisWorkbook" part of the VBA project you can add something like

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim strPath As String
'put the location and name of your batch file here
strPath = "C:\YourFolder\YourBatchFile.bat"

Call Shell(strPath)

End Sub
```

See this [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814737(v=office.14).aspx) if you are not sure about using VBA code

Comment: it won't work, unless you know how to insert that vba into excel file that i do not have direct access to it. Employee uses it in his own machine and i need to incorporate it silently as a spider

Comment: @orangutangas then I do not think you can do this with Excel as you would need macro permissions etc. In order for something to work like this you would require a program that monitors the target's computer for the specific opening of the file in question - this is generally specific admin network software or spyware.

Comment: Stephan in post above gave me a hint. It should be batch script not vba firstly, as somehow i need to open excel from batch when excel document is double -clicked

Answer (score 0):

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\CIMV2") 
Set objEvents = objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery _
    ("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStopTrace")

Do
    Set objReceivedEvent = objEvents.NextEvent
    msgbox objReceivedEvent.ProcessName
If lcase(objReceivedEvent.ProcessName) = lcase("Notepad.exe") then 
    Msgbox "Process exited with exit code " & objReceivedEvent.ExitStatus
    WshShell.Run "c:\Windows\notepad.exe", 1, false
End If

Loop
```

This is a vbs script monitoring all program stops. You can use Win32_ProcessStopTrace, Win32_ProcessStartStopTrace, or Win32_ProcessStartTrace.

This is meant to replace a batch file. To write a log

```
Set Fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set File = Fso.CreateTextFile("c:\folder\filename", True)
    file.writeline "text"
```

Comment: thank you. what will it do exactly? seein that it shows process names, but do not understand a bit.

Comment: Try it. It shows names pf programs starting, stopping, or starting and stopping.

Comment: thank you once again. so if that script shows that program starts will it be possible to launch batch file on opened document? or is it very tough task?